Lerp() issues: cannot convert argument from int to float
I am using Godot 4.3, it is giving me this error and when I change 0 to 0.0, the character stops moving. If I change the last parameter to an integer also it still shoots an error:
extends CharacterBody3D


var myVelocity = Vector3(0,0,0)
const SPEED = 6

func _ready() -> void:
    pass # Replace with function body.

func _physics_process(delta: float) -> void:
    
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right") and Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        velocity.x = 0
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_right"):
        myVelocity.x = SPEED
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_left"):
        myVelocity.x = -SPEED
    else:
        myVelocity.z = lerp(myVelocity.z,0,0.1)

        
    if Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up") and Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        velocity.z = 0
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_up"):
        myVelocity.z = -SPEED
    elif Input.is_action_pressed("ui_down"):
        myVelocity.z = SPEED
    else:
        myVelocity.z = lerp(myVelocity.z,0,0.1)

        
    velocity = myVelocity
    move_and_slide()


I copy-pasted your code in a sample project and (after fixing the errors by replacing 0 with 0.0) it seems to work and the character moves fine.

From the docs:

Both from and to must be the same type.

Since a Vector3's components are of type float the second argument to lerp also has to be a float: lerp(myVelocity.z, 0.0, 0.1).
As for this:

when i change 0 to 0.0, the character stops moving

If your character stops moving even when you are pressing a movement key that is probably due to some other bug. Try removing one piece of code at a time and see which piece of code is responsible for this behaviour.

Thanks. I'll try it out
